# How to use cordova-plugin-ble-central's API Scan( ) from ionic1 to ionic3

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to migrate a project from ionic1 to ionic3, but cordova-plugin-ble-central has some problems

ionic1

```
function quickScan( ) {
      var q = $ble.scan([], 3);
          q.then(function() {
        /* Done scanning */
        if (!sys.fsm.is("LISTING")) {
            setNumScans(0);
            return;
         }

        if (sys.numScans > 0)
        setNumScans(sys.numScans - 1);

        if (sys.numScans > 0) {
        quickScan();
        } else {
        if (sys.fsm.is("LISTING")) {
        sys.fsm.abort();
        sys.listOkCb(null);
        }
         }
    }, function(err) {
        /* Scanning Error */
        sys.fsm.abort();
        sys.listErrCb(err);
         }, function(dev) {
        /* New device found */
        addAndReportDevice(dev);
         });
    }
```

ionic3

```
       quickScan( ) {
       let q = this.Ble.scan([], 3)
        q.toPromise().then(function() {
        /* Done scanning */
        if (!this.fsm.is("LISTING")) {
        this.setNumScans(0);
          return;
     }
        if (this.numScans > 0)
        this.setNumScans(this.numScans - 1);

        if (this.numScans > 0) {
        this.quickScan();
     }else {
        console.log("BLE done scanning");
        if (this.fsm.is("LISTING")) {
        this.fsm.abort();
        this.listOkCb(null);
     }
      }
      },function(err) {
        /* Scanning Error */
        this.fsm.abort();
        this.listErrCb(err);
        /* New device found */
        this.addAndReportDevice(this.dev);
       });
     }
```

error message:TypeError: Cannot read property ‘scan’ of undefined.

I am not sure the usage of Scan() has changed.

Please tell me how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using [native BLE plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ble) for ionic 3. Here is a simple example how you can use it:

1) Import the BLE module in your app.module

```
import { BLE } from '@ionic-native/ble';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [
        BLE
    ]
}
```

2) In your page component inject the BLE module

```
constructor( private ble: BLE ) { ... }
```

3) Scan for nearby BLE devices like this:

```
const bleServices = ["service-uuid-you-want-to-scan-for"];

this.ble.startScan(bleServices).subscribe(
    device => { console.log('Discovered device:', JSON.stringify(device)); },
    error  => { console.log('Scan error:', error); }
);
```

Afterwards you can connect to your device using its device id `this.ble.connect(device.id)`

Comment: Appear TypeError: Cannot read property ‘startscan’ of undefined.
I think this problem is caused by another problem, not the problem of BLE'API.
Thank you for your answer.