# Error importing Cordova BLE plugin within ionic 6 framework

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to use Cordova plugin within ionic.
I installed the plugin with this command:

> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ble-central

And imported within my app.modules.ts file as follows:

```
import {BlE} from 'cordova-plugin-ble-central';
```

app.modules.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from @ionic/angular';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { BLE } from 'cordova-plugin-ble-central';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(),AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [BLE, { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

When running the application with  *ionic serve* command I am greeted with this error.

> Error: src/app/app.module.ts:10:19 - error TS2306: File
> '/Users/XXXX/Documents/Apps/SLC/node_modules/cordova-plugin-ble-central/types.d.ts'
> is not a module.

Have I imported this plugin correctly? If not, what is the correct way to import this plugin?

Attempted the solution provided at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57753162/how-to-use-cordova-plugin-ble-centrals-api-scan-from-ionic1-to-ionic3) but the error still is persistent in version 6.

Thanks

Comment: @E.Maggini I've changed my program similar to the answer and reinstalled the plugin with the commands in the link provided, and now getting the error `Cannot find module '@ionic-native/ble' or its corresponding type declarations.`

Comment: please post your app.module.ts

Comment: @E.Maggini Posted my app.moduke.ts.